# How to remove the thick focus border from controls in MAUI?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, winui-3

I'm using the default MAUI application generated by Visual Studio as a starting point. I have added custom focus borders for VisualState `Focused` and it works fine when focusing with the mouse. However, when navigating the form with Tab key, the default black frame appears around the focused buttons.

[image: button with black frame]

Some WinUI articles suggest that `UseSystemFocusVisuals` should work. So I have done the following in my App.xaml in Windows folder:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    <x:Boolean x:Key="UseSystemFocusVisuals">False</x:Boolean>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

Unfortunately, it did not work on Buttons. However, at least the `TextControl` settings worked for Entry elements. So, in general, the Resources section is being applied, it's just that UseSystemFocusVisuals seems to have no effect on Button controls. Checkboxes and radios have the same problem.

How do I get rid of these globally, without extending all the controls?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I notice what is common about those elements is that they don't take text input. There is no sustained user interaction; no need on mobile devices (that lack keyboard and mouse) to consider such elements "focusable". IIRC, because of this, Xamarin.Forms didn't consider them as having focus (maybe Android and iOS native controls don't?). The symptoms suggest Maui has retained that limitation. Sounds like a Maui bug. If no one comes up with a solution, you could add it as an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues.

Comment: Firstly MAUI is different from WinUI. The [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.usesystemfocusvisuals) which you are referring is for *Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls*. Whereas int the sample application which you created has *Button* from *Windows.Maui.Controls*; which doesn't have `UseSystemFocusVisuals` property. Coming back to your question, i do not think there is property exposed to turn this off. This possibly a feature request i guess.

Comment: @dhilmathy  I was adding those flags under Windows platform folder, where it is actually a WinUI3 Button (MAUI Button is the layer above it). But I found a solution, it turned out I had to add UseSystemFocusVisuals for specific controls. That's confusing - some focus bordering flags work globally and some don't.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging and experimenting, I found a workaround:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
```

So, the global `UseSystemFocusVisuals` did not work but it started working when I added it to each control style separately.