# How to remove .NET MAUI ListViewItem Focus Visuals?

Tags: maui

I am having a hard time removing the black border (focus visuals) around the items of my ListView in .NET MAUI.

[image: Focus Visuals Around ListView Item]

I tried overriding some styles of in the App.xml file of the WinUI platform as such without success:

```
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItemPresenter">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
    
    <xaml:Thickness x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness">0,0,0,0</xaml:Thickness>
    <x:Boolean x:Key="ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorVisualEnabled">False</x:Boolean>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style>
   ...
```

Nothing's working and I'm losing hope. These blocky focus visuals seriously hinder the look and feel of the application. I'm not against such indicators, but I'd like to be able to style them at a minimum.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the code you provided and also tried to modify default style of ListView/ListViewItem 's properties but failed.

I also tested this [case's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73429058/how-to-remove-the-thick-focus-border-from-controls-in-maui) but still failed:

```xml
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
```

I think it would be problem at the Windows system level. You can report it as an issue or a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll consider it. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, please accept it as an answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!